# Reference for the Hodge diamond of the Iwasawa threefold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, hodge-theory

Let $X = G/\Gamma$ denote the Iwasawa threefold, where

$$G = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & z_1 & z_3\\ 0 & 1 & z_2\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} : z_1, z_2, z_3 \in \mathbb{C} \right\},$$

and $\Gamma$ is the discrete subgroup $$\Gamma=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & z_1 & z_3\\ 0 & 1 & z_2\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} : z_1, z_2, z_3 \in \mathbb{Z}[i] \right\}.$$

> Can anyone point to a reference for the Hodge diamond of $X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should have waited a few minutes, it's on page 49 of Danielle Angela's *Cohomological aspects of non-Kähler manifolds*: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.0524.pdf